# Simple proof that matrices similar of $E_{13}$ square to 0?

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $E_{13}:=\pmatrix{0 &0 & 1\\0 &0 &0\\0&0&0}.$ I can already show that for $g\in GL(3,\mathbb{C})$, it follows that $(gE_{13}g^{-1})^2=0.$ It is an absolutely horrendous calculation to brute force, each element of the resulting $3\times 3$ matrix is roughly 9 inches long when I write really small on paper, before it reduces to 0.

Surely there is a more elegant proof that doesn't involve such tedious computation. Thanks.

Comment: your matrix is nilpotent  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(gE_{13}g^{-1})^2=gE_{13}g^{-1}gE_{13}g^{-1}=gE_{13}E_{13}g^{-1}=g0g^{-1}=0$$